# C++ Move a unique_ptr to a vector and continue using it

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I´m starting playing around with `std::unique_ptr` and I just don´t want to mess up things.

On my code, I´m creating a `std::unique_ptr`, storing it on a `vector` for later use in another context and continue using the pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


   class MyClass {
    public: 
         void doWhatever ()
         {
            std::cout << "Var = " << variable << std::endl;
         }

         int variable = 0;
    };

    class Controller {
    public: 
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> instances;

    };

    class OtherClass {
    public: 
        void myFunction()
        {
           Controller control;
           std::unique_ptr<MyClass> p(new MyClass);
           control.instances.push_back(std::move(p));

           // Continue using p. 

           p->doWhatever(); // Is this valid ?
           p->variable = 10;  // Is this valid ?
           p->doWhatever(); // Is this valid ?
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        OtherClass cl;
        cl.myFunction();
    }
```

The code compiles, but I´m getting segmentation fault on execution.

I imagine that calls to `p` after moving the pointer to the vector are invalid.... If so, what would be the solution here ? Moving to a shared_ptr ?

OBS: I cannot move to vector *after* using the pointer. In real application this will be running on a multi-threaded environment where one thead is using the vector data and the other continue using the original pointer `p`.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: After doing `std::move(p)` you're __not__ allowed to use `p` anymore!

Comment: @zenith `p` itself can be (re)used, `*p` can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of unique pointer says it all. It is meant to be completely unique so when it goes out of scope it can be safely deleted.

When you use `std::move` on the pointer, it casts it to a rvalue reference hat then invokes the move constructor, meaning it is moved, not copied. It is just like if you move a plate from the dishwasher to the cabinet, it isn't in the dishwasher. In code, that means that the `unique_ptr` that is moved from is set to  `nullptr`

Alternatives:

1. Use a ref counted `shared_ptr`. This will allow you to have multiple instances and after the last one is deleted the destructor will be called. Another plus of using this is that the vector could  store `weak_ptr`s if it shouldn't keep the object from being destroyed.
2. Cache the raw pointer before using `std::move` on the `unique_ptr` to move it into the `vector`. This potentially unsafe because if you try to use that pointer after the vector is destroyed it is undefined behaviors because it would be a dangling reference.

Comment: Change the type to `shared_ptr` would be enough here or some more task is needed ?

Comment: If you use a `shared_ptr` in both the vector and the original ptr it should work fine. Also, when constructing the `shared_ptr` consider using `make_shared` because it is one less allocation (this is also useful for `unique_ptr`s with `make_unique`) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

Comment: Worked like a charm... We need to remove the `std::move` also from the assignment. Definitive code: `std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p = make_shared<MyClass>(new MyClass);
        control.instances.push_back(p)`

Comment: Never lightly use a `shared_ptr`. They are expensive and only sensible if you're dealing with objects that lack a clear ownership. In the OP, there is no sense of ownership, so one cannot really make a recommendation.

Comment: @Walter they are fairly cheap if you aren't doing lots of copies and deletions. The atomic increment is the most expensive part other than the extra memory requirements.

Comment: I never realized you could cast `unique_ptr`s into hats ! C++ is a wonderful language :b

Comment: In addition to the previous note on replacing `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr` it's important to remove the std::move call. That way it is copy constructed instead of move constructed.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, no it is not valid to use **any** object after you've moved it. EDIT: Unless you are calling a function that has no preconditions (Thanks, Benjamin Lindley).

This is because when you `std::move` a `unique_ptr`, you are transferring ownership of that memory to another `unique_ptr`. (What's really happening is that `std::move` marks your `unique_ptr` as an r-value reference, and then the constructor for the other `unique_ptr` sees this and gleefully performs pointer stealing). The `unique_ptr` that you've moved into can now do whatever it wants, including delete the memory and invalidate any other reference you have.

You can dereference the pointer into a raw pointer (via `unique_ptr::get()`) to access what it's pointing at, and then move the unique pointer into the vector. However, the whole idea of a `unique_ptr` is sole ownership; your raw pointer could at any time become invalid.

Comment: You can use objects that have been moved from. As long as the operations you perform don't have any preconditions. And once you've verified preconditions, you're free to use the object as normal.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thank you for that. A case I've not considered!